# Java: Why/what are these threads monitoring?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithreaded Java application which splits an image into 4 chunks, then 4 threads (I have a quad-core CPU) each work on an individual chunk of the image, converting it to grayscale.

I found that it was quite slow for some reason, so I used the NetBeans profiler and found that the threads were "monitoring" (waiting) quite a lot. For example,

[image: this]

(green = running, red = monitoring)

I experimented with different numbers of threads, e.g. 2, and found that this still happened (the only time it didn't happen was with 1 thread).

Inside the threads, I commented out bits of their code until I narrowed the "big delay" down to this statement:

```
newImage.setRGB(i,j,newColor.getRGB()); // Write the new value for that pixel
```

If this is commented out, the code runs MUCH (almost 5x) faster, and there is NO thread monitoring:

[image]

So why does that one line cause so much delay? Is it the Color library (alongside BufferedImage)? Right now I'm going to try and get an array of ints as the RGB values instead of using a Color object and see how that goes.

Here is the source code:

PixelsManipulation.java (main class):

```
public final class PixelsManipulation{

private static Sequential sequentialGrayscaler = new Sequential();  

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {  

    File file = new File("src/pixelsmanipulation/hiresimage.jpg");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file  

    int rows = 2; // 2 rows and 2 cols will split the image into quarters
    int cols = 2;  
    int chunks = rows * cols; // 4 chunks, one for each quarter of the image  
    int chunkWidth = image.getWidth() / cols; // determines the chunk width and height  
    int chunkHeight = image.getHeight() / rows;  
    int count = 0;  
    BufferedImage imgs[] = new BufferedImage[chunks]; // Array to hold image chunks  

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {  
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {  
            //Initialize the image array with image chunks  
            imgs[count] = new BufferedImage(chunkWidth, chunkHeight, image.getType());  
            // draws the image chunk  

            Graphics2D gr = imgs[count++].createGraphics(); // Actually create an image for us to use
            gr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, chunkWidth, chunkHeight, chunkWidth * y, chunkHeight * x, chunkWidth * y + chunkWidth, chunkHeight * x + chunkHeight, null);  
            gr.dispose();

        }  
    } 

    //writing mini images into image files  
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {  
        ImageIO.write(imgs[i], "jpg", new File("img" + i + ".jpg"));  
    }  
    System.out.println("Mini images created");  

    // Start threads with their respective quarters (chunks) of the image to work on
    // I have a quad-core machine, so I can only use 4 threads on my CPU
    Parallel parallelGrayscaler = new Parallel("thread-1", imgs[0]);
    Parallel parallelGrayscaler2 = new Parallel("thread-2", imgs[1]);
    Parallel parallelGrayscaler3 = new Parallel("thread-3", imgs[2]);
    Parallel parallelGrayscaler4 = new Parallel("thread-4", imgs[3]);

    // Sequential:
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    sequentialGrayscaler.ConvertToGrayscale(image);

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Sequential code executed in " + elapsedTime + " ms.");

    // Multithreaded (parallel):
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    parallelGrayscaler.start();
    parallelGrayscaler2.start();
    parallelGrayscaler3.start();
    parallelGrayscaler4.start();

    // Main waits for threads to finish so that the program doesn't "end" (i.e. stop measuring time) before the threads finish
    parallelGrayscaler.join();
    parallelGrayscaler2.join();
    parallelGrayscaler3.join();
    parallelGrayscaler4.join();

    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Multithreaded (parallel) code executed in " + elapsedTime + " ms.");
}
}
```

Parallel.java:

```
// Let each of the 4 threads work on a different quarter of the image
public class Parallel extends Thread{//implements Runnable{

private String threadName;
private static BufferedImage myImage; // Calling it "my" image because each thread will have its own unique quarter of the image to work on
private static int width, height; // Image params

Parallel(String name, BufferedImage image){
    threadName = name;
    System.out.println("Creating "+ threadName);
    myImage = image;
    width = myImage.getWidth();
    height = myImage.getHeight();

}

public void run(){
    System.out.println("Running " + threadName);

    // Pixel by pixel (for our quarter of the image)
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){

            // Traversing the image and converting the RGB values (doing the same thing as the sequential code but on a smaller scale)
            Color c = new Color(myImage.getRGB(i,j));

            int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299);
            int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587);
            int blue  = (int)(c.getBlue() * 0.114);

            Color newColor = new Color(red + green + blue, red + green + blue, red + green + blue);

            myImage.setRGB(i,j,newColor.getRGB()); // Write the new value for that pixel


        }
    }

    File output = new File("src/pixelsmanipulation/"+threadName+"grayscale.jpg"); // Put it in a "lower level" folder so we can see it in the project view
    try {
        ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", output);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Parallel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting. ---");
}
}
```

I am a beginner at threading in Java (as well as using BufferedImage), just curious as to why it's so slow.

Comment: obviously there is something missing because I dont see newImage anywhere created/declared

Comment: setRgb is synchronized iirc

Comment: @gpasch that was something I meant to change before copy-pasting, it should have been myImage. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is `Parallel.myImage` static? This will cause all the threads to share the same image. That might explain why they are waiting on each other.

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked that. You're right, that would explain why they're all waiting on each other to finish.